# C# Xml Serialization Inline Elements

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

Is there a way to force the XML serializer to add an element as inline rather than with the Value layout.  I basically have just a giant list of structs and I'd like to add an inline element to each sub element that is enabled.

```
<main>
<item>
  <value>1</value>
  <name>Alphabet</name>
</item>
...
</main>
```

I basically want to add:

```
<item Enabled="true">
```

if the element block is enabled.  IS there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just mark the Enabled property with the `XmlAttributeAttribute`:

```
[XmlAttribute("Enabled")]
public bool Enabled { get; set; }
```

Documentation on the attributes that control xml serialization can be found on MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks.  Exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

**XmlAttributeAttribute**

The XmlAttributeAttribute attribute allows you to specify that a member should be serialized as an attribute and what that attribute should be named. Only simple data can be used as an attribute because an attribute can only represent a single value.
Collapse

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace XmlEntities {
    [XmlRoot("XmlDocRoot")]
    public class RootClass {
        private int attribute_id;

        [XmlAttribute("id")]
        public int Id {
            get { return attribute_id; }
            set { attribute_id = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

This will serialize to something similar to this...
Collapse

```
<XmlDocRoot id="1" />
```

more info check this answer on SO : [How to add attributes for C# XML Serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012360/how-to-add-attributes-for-c-xml-serialization)